# graph library for scala

Tags: scala, graph

Is there a good library (or wrapper to Java library) for graphs, and/or graph algorithms in scala?

[This one](http://code.google.com/p/scala-graphs/) seems to be quite dead. [This](http://en.literateprograms.org/Dijkstra's_algorithm_(Scala)) is an example for the Dijkstra algorithm in scala, but I'm looking for a library a-la [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: though another answer is accepted, I strongly recommend scalax.collection.Graph, see http://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-graph/wiki It was mentioned in the other answer, but it is quite stable now ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't understand why we're being asked to review ancient history.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have developed a small graph library for the apparat project. You can take a look at it [here](http://code.google.com/p/apparat/source/browse/#hg%2Fapparat-core%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fscala%2Fapparat%2Fgraph). It is not purely functional and not a zipper graph but does a good job for us. You get also mutable and immutable graphs.

Here is a simple example for graph creation:

```
implicit val factory = DefaultEdge[String](_, _)
val G = Graph(
  "Entry" -> "A",
  "A" -> "B",
  "B" -> "C",
  "B" -> "D",
  "D" -> "F",
  "F" -> "E",
  "E" -> "F",
  "E" -> "C",
  "C" -> "A",
  "C" -> "Exit")
G.dotExport to Console.out
```

Finding SCCs and subcomponents

```
G.sccs foreach println
G.sccs map { _.entry } foreach println
G.sccs filter { _.canSearch } map { _.subcomponents } foreach { _ foreach println }
```

Traversal

```
for(x <- G.topsort) println(x)
for(x <- G.dft(y)) println(x)
```

The current drawback is that the library is supporting only invariant types and not feature complete for a whole graph library.

Answer (score 24):

There is a [current call-for-comments](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-collection-Graph-Preliminary-td3059277.html) to create a scala.collection.Graph built-in into the Scala library.

Also, how about developing a Scala wrapper for JGraphT?

**UPDATE**

[Graph for Scala](https://github.com/scala-graph/scala-graph) is now beyond the discussion stage, and a work-in-progress.

Comment: now at https://github.com/scala-graph/scala-graph

Comment: what's different from https://github.com/twitter/cassovary?

Answer (score 4):

Why not [Jung](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) ? and also [Piccolo2D](http://www.piccolo2d.org/) for graphics? (both JVM based).

Comment: @sw: Jung doesn't have special Scala bindings does it?  One can of course use any Java graph library.

Comment: @Rex_Kerr you can import every Java class, why do you need a special binding?

Comment: @sw because those bindings can interact better with scala's structures, such as lambda expressions (for instance g.nodes.forall(_.weight > 10))

Answer (score 2):

Gremlin-Scala is a thin thin Scala wrapper for Gremlin, a graph DSL for traversing a number of graph databases including Neo4j, OrientDB, DEX, InfiniteGraph, Titan, Rexster graph server, and Sesame 2.0 compliant RDF stores.

https://github.com/mpollmeier/gremlin-scala

Note: I am biased as I'm the author ;)